# how to Create a combobox in groovy

Tags: swing, groovy

Can you tell me why this doesnt work in Groovy script?
I'm trying to find a piece of code most close to my needs and edit it, but it prompts an error.  The script runs well in java though, at least thats what the website says. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridLayoutDemo.java

I'm trying yo run it from SOAPUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayoutDemo extends JFrame {
    static final String gapList[] = {"0", "10", "15", "20"};
    final static int maxGap = 20;
    JComboBox horGapComboBox;
    JComboBox verGapComboBox;
    JButton applyButton = new JButton("Apply gaps");
    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);

    public GridLayoutDemo(String name) {
        super(name);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void initGaps() {
        horGapComboBox = new JComboBox(gapList);
        verGapComboBox = new JComboBox(gapList);
    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        initGaps();
        final JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel();
        compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));

        //Set up components preferred size
        JButton b = new JButton("Just fake button");
        Dimension buttonSize = b.getPreferredSize();
        compsToExperiment.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(buttonSize.getWidth() * 2.5)+maxGap,
                (int)(buttonSize.getHeight() * 3.5)+maxGap * 2));

        //Add buttons to experiment with Grid Layout
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Long-Named Button 4"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("5"));

        //Add controls to set up horizontal and vertical gaps
        controls.add(new Label("Horizontal gap:"));
        controls.add(new Label("Vertical gap:"));
        controls.add(new Label(" "));
        controls.add(horGapComboBox);
        controls.add(verGapComboBox);
        controls.add(applyButton);

        //Process the Apply gaps button press
        applyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //Get the horizontal gap value
                String horGap = (String)horGapComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                //Get the vertical gap value
                String verGap = (String)verGapComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                //Set up the horizontal gap value
                experimentLayout.setHgap(Integer.parseInt(horGap));
                //Set up the vertical gap value
                experimentLayout.setVgap(Integer.parseInt(verGap));
                //Set up the layout of the buttons
                experimentLayout.layoutContainer(compsToExperiment);
            }
        });
        pane.add(compsToExperiment, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(new JSeparator(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method is invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        GridLayoutDemo frame = new GridLayoutDemo("GridLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Set up the content pane.
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you would have mentioned **what** error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please mention the error you get.

Not all Java syntax supported 1:1 in Groovy though most is.
Actually there are two things in one line that are not supported in Groovy like that.

1. The quite uncommon (in Java) `String gapList[]` syntax is not supported and should be `String[] gapList` instead.
2. Array initializer syntax like `{"0", "10", "15", "20"}` is not supported in Groovy, instead you need to write a list literal and cast it to the array type like `["0", "10", "15", "20"] as String[]`. Actually as your variable you are assigning to is typed, the cast can even be made implcitly, so `["0", "10", "15", "20"]` is enough.

So replace

```
static final String gapList[] = {"0", "10", "15", "20"};
```

by

```
static final String[] gapList = ["0", "10", "15", "20"];
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: yes, that was it. unfortunately, it still prompts and error ) 
"groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class GridLayoutDemo. Reason: java.lang.InstantiationException: GridLayoutDemo"

but thank you

Comment: From a first look I guess you should add a default constructor. But this depends on how you try to use this class.